# How to find top 5 peaks through findpeaks

Tags: matlab

I have got a spectrum after FFT. I want to find the top 5 peaks of that spectrum. Can it be done using findpeaks?

Comment: you should read the documentation before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
% finds all peaks and returns them, largest first
[peakVals,peakLocs]=findpeaks(data,'sortstr','descend');
```

Then just take the first five values. If it takes a long time to run, try also specifying `minpeakheight`.

Answer (score 1):

Should be no problem [(help page)](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html)

```
[peakVals,peakLocs]=findpeaks(data,'npeaks',5);
```

Comment: David that gives me the first 5 peaks, not the maximum 5.